# Only Some Gmails open iCalendar invites

Tags: icalendar

I have an issue where only some gmails open/recognize my .ics files my app sends. It seems it works fine with regular gmail accounts but google business account emails don't automatically open the invite or automatically put it on the user's calendar. Also, the invite is not automatically opened on some phones.

```
function sendevent($to, $from, $fromname, $subject, $body, $method, $start, $end, $id, $app_date, $location, $status){
    $company=Company::find_by_id($_SESSION['compid']);
    $tz = $company->timezone();
    if(!empty($tz)){$tzid = ";TZID=".$tz;}else{$tzid = ";TZID=America/Chicago";}
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->FromName = $fromname;
    $mail->From = $from;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $vcal = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
    $vcal .= "PRODID:-//SiteArmorInc//ContractorsCloud.com//EN\n";
    $vcal .= "VERSION:2.0\n";
    $vcal .= "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n";
    $vcal .= "METHOD:REQUEST\n";
    $vcal .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
    $vcal .= "DTSTART".$tzid.":".date("Ymd\THi00", strtotime($start))."\n";
    $vcal .= "DTEND".$tzid.":".date("Ymd\THi00", strtotime($end))."\n";
    $vcal .= "DTSTAMP".$tzid.":".date("Ymd\THi00", time())."\n";
    $vcal .= "ORGANIZER;CN=".$from.":mailto:".$from."\n";
    $vcal .= "UID:".$id."\n";
    $vcal .= "ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPT;RSVP=TRUE;CN=".$to.";X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:".$to."\n";
    $vcal .= "CREATED".$tzid.":".date("Ymd\THi00", strtotime($app_date))."\n";
    $vcal .= "DESCRIPTION:".str_replace("\n", "\N",str_replace(",","\,",$body))."\n";
    $vcal .= "LOCATION:".str_replace(",","\,",$location)."\n";
    $vcal .= "LAST-MODIFIED".$tzid.":".date("Ymd\THi00", time())."\n";
    $vcal .= "SEQUENCE:0\n";
    $vcal .= "STATUS:CONFIRMED\n";
    $vcal .= "SUMMARY:".str_replace(",","\,",$subject)."\n";
    $vcal .= "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n";
    $vcal .= "END:VEVENT\n";
    $vcal .= "END:VCALENDAR\n";

    $mail->AddStringAttachment($vcal, "ccloud_invite.ics", "8bit", "text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST");
    $mail->Body = $body;
    if($mail->Send()){return true;}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure if this is the root cause but line ending are suppose to be CRLF, \r\n.

Comment: I have the same problem, also with a business account. Anybody?